# BorderLayout with jlabels side by side

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

How can I make 2 labels align with each other in a borderLayout.

```
 panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("123.jpg"), SwingConstants.LEFT),BorderLayout.NORTH);
  panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("123.jpg")), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

I want it so that these 2 images are beside each other in the north side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another panel for hold labels.

```
JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
labelPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("123.jpg"));
labelPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("123.jpg"));

panel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```